# Call custom mysql function from laravel helper

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, mysql-error-1064

I created a helper to run a custom function in mysql, I'm trying to match
   parameters found in the DB, so it should return X if it's succesful.

Blade :

```
 @foreach($ficha as $est)
         @foreach($est->equipos as $eq)
            @foreach($eq->parametros as $param)

             <p>{{ tiene_parametro_ficha($param->nombre ,$ficha->first()->id) }}</p>   //FUNCTION, pass 2 values

               @endforeach      
            @endforeach
         @endforeach
```

Helper:

```
 function tiene_parametro_ficha($param, $id_est)
  {
   $queries =DB::select("tiene_parametro_ficha($param, $id_est)");  //I tried alias Result , it gives error too
 }
```

Mysql Function :

```
  BEGIN
  DECLARE mivar INT;
  SET @PAR=PARAM;
  SET @ID_EST = ID_EST;


 SELECT  (if((p.nombre = @PAR),1,0)) INTO mivar
 FROM estacion AS e
        INNER JOIN equipo_estacion AS ee ON ee.estacion_id = @ID_EST
        INNER JOIN equipo AS eq ON eq.id = ee.equipo_id
        INNER JOIN equipo_parametro AS e_p ON e_p.equipo_id = eq.id
        INNER JOIN parametro AS p ON p.id = e_p.parametro_id
      WHERE p.nombre = @PAR AND ee.estado ="activo" AND
      eq.deleted_at IS NULL LIMIT 1;

    CASE mivar
    WHEN 1 THEN
    RETURN 'X';
    WHEN 0 THEN
    RETURN '0'; 
    ELSE
    RETURN '';
   END CASE;
   END
```

Error i get
  [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For sure you are missing `SELECT` in your query.

Instead of:

```
$queries = DB::select("tiene_parametro_ficha($param, $id_est)");
```

use:

```
$queries = DB::select("SELECT tiene_parametro_ficha($param, $id_est)");
```

[Reference for raw queries](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#running-queries)

Also, please be aware: running any query from a view like this is very bad practice. You should run those functions (and other queries) in a controller and use the result in the Blade view.